# C# WPF Selection Changed by Mouse or Keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, keyboard, selectionchanged

i have inserted a WPF Combobox in my Projekt. Currently i have a keydown event in the combobox. Now i have the problem that i would also select an Item with the mouse. If i use a selectionchanged event it will also executed if it is changed via keyboard. If i use a mousekeydown event it acts also if i don't know how tp get the clicked item. See Example:

```
 private void CMB_Adresse_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Down || e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Up)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.CMB_Adresse_Temp = ((string)CMB_Adresse.SelectedItem);
                }
                else
                {
```

Comment: The right way to implement this in WPF is to create a ViewModel to hold your List of values and Selected value and bind the ComboBox `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` to that. That way you don't have to worry if the user selected the item with the Mouse, Keyboard, or by placing a magnet in the computer's RAM.

Comment: HighCore is right. Generally speaking you shouldn't use events when using WPF, especially not things like OnSelectedItemChanged. On the other hand if you want to write WPF controls (not user-controls), then you should use keyup and stuff...